# Nuxt.js with Typeform causes me to force reload page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, typeform

I am making my own personal webdesign website but I can't wrap my head around this problem.

How it happens:
When I **navigate** from any page to my contact-page (where the Typeform is), the Typeform is simply not showing. When I **reload** the contact-page itself, it works as it is expected.

I am loading the Typeform script this way:
*contact.vue*

```
head () {
        return {
            script: [
                { src: 'https://embed.typeform.com/embed.js' }
            ]
        }
    }
```

and I am embedding it in the template this way:

```
<div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://url-to-my-form" 
                    data-transparency="50" data-hide-headers=true data-hide-footer=true
                    style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
                <div style="font-size: 12px;color: #999;opacity: 0.5; padding-top: 5px;"></div>
```

I am following all the steps they provided, but it doesn't seem to work...
I am also getting the following errors in my console but I don't think they are relevant because the form works when I reload the contact-page:

```
[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://aaron479753.typeform.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https:".


GET https://cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/9at6spGDYXelHDdz4r0cP73b3wV1f0ri/analytics.min.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

note: I am developing on localhost so that's why HTTPS is not enabled.

Thanks in advance!
Aaron

Edit:
[the form when I reload the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BXzN.png)

[the form when I go to (for example) /home and then back to /contanct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfm5M.png)

Comment: I also still have this issue. would love to resolve this console error for my site https://www.soheco.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using an NPM package provided by [jgmullor](http://github.com/jgmullor/nuxt-typeform), this resolved the issue!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-typeform